# AMDPRO 17.30 and my laptop graphics card doesnt work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

Hello everyone i am aware this is a popular topic and many people have the same problem as i have, but when i try apply the solutions i read they don't seem to fit to my problem, so here is my problem :

I recently bought a dell Inspiron 5567 with an r7 graphics card

> > lspci | grep Display
>
> 01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
>   Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] (rev c3)

I have installed the AMDPRO 17.30(or i think i have)

> dpkg -l amdgpu-pro

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold |

> Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad) ||/ Name
>   Version Architecture Description
>   +++-==============-============-============-================================= ii amdgpu-pro 17.30-465504 amd64 Meta package to install amdgpu Pr

and on its release notes its says that its supports my graphics card 
[17.30 release notes](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx)

After the drivers were installed i got in a login loop which i solved with the help of this community, but the problem is that when i go to System Settings on the Details tab i see the Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2) as the default graphics card.

The questions are, did i install the drivers correctly? If yes why doesn't Ubuntu uses the AMD card as default since the drivers were installed, and finally how can i make it work?

P.S. I have read that downgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 is a possible solution but with the 17.30 drivers more AMD cards became compatible with Ubuntu 16,04, and i wanted to ask the community for a possible solution before downgrading to 14.04.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-newer-amdgpu-driver-ubuntu-1604lts-dennis-mungai

Comment: How did you solve the login loop problem without uninstalling amdgpu 17.30?

Comment: I entered the console using Ctrl Alt f6 then in went to the folder that the driver was extracted and reinstalled it using the --px commnad

Answer (score 1):

It's because usually having a stronger GPU by default is unwanted *(more on laptops, not so much on desktops)*. It consumes more power for no reason as integrated GPU is powerful enough to run light graphics workloads like a desktop, even with effects enabled like wobbly or burning windows.

To run an application on dGPU you can use `DRI_PRIME` variable. E.g. here is the output from my laptop:

```
$             glxinfo | grep evice
    Device: AMD SUMO (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.13.3-1-zen, LLVM 6.0.0) (0x9641)
$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep evice
    Device: AMD TURKS (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.13.3-1-zen, LLVM 6.0.0) (0x6741)
```

If you really want to run whole desktop on dGPU, you can override the variable globally *(I think you can even override some kernel parameters, but I didn't explore that)*. Add into `/etc/environment` this line:

```
DRI_PRIME=1
```

For the record, it might be useful to know that assigning a variable directly, like I did in example with glxinfo, [might not always work as opposed to `export`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export/1158231#1158231). However the file `/etc/environment` accepts syntax specifically without export.

And note, AMD is focused on radeonsi driver, the proprietary one is still here just because of OpenGL compatibility profile used by CAD software. The profile is unsupported by Mesa, for it's optional and mixing old OpenGL with modern one is frowned upon. Anyway, what I wanted to say is, [the default driver is much faster than AMDGPU-pro](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amdgpu-1730-radeonsi&num=1) *(well, given you're using it recent enough)*.

---

**UPD:** regarding the naming convention — different models of GPUs are often built on the same architecture from the driver point of view, i.e. the interrupts, registers, assembly… The difference is usually in amount of some specific stuff, like VRAM, ALUs, bus, etc. In these cases drivers usually do not take compare `if gpu_model=x then do y because the number of ALUs smaller or bigger`, instead they're comparing to amounts directly. The reason is that any time a new GPU model could appear, which might differ in just, say, amount of VRAM *(but not interrupts or other important things)* — can you imagine having to rewrite all driver stuff for this reason? Worse, peoples have to update the driver for the GPU to be supported, whereas by having a generic comparison to amount of VRAM, the "new GPU" would be even supported by drivers from the time the GPU didn't exist.

So, even though it's sad that you don't see the model name you expected, but that not necessarily means something bad is going on.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time to answer my question but the problem remained, i did a test that Dell support suggested, i installed windows to see if there was something wrong with my graphics card, and then it hit me, when i installed the amd windows drivers it stated that my laptop uses the r7 m445 while ubuntu stated that i use the r7 245 when i used the lspci command. Now i am possitive that amd and linux dont get along , i am kinda dissapointed it will never work probablly because amd wont release a proper driver that works with ubuntu.

Comment: @Aenarion I don't understand you. First, what do you mean by "lspci states that r7 245 is used" — do you have any particular field in mind? Second: wasn't that what you wanted anyway? Third: `DRI_PRIME` variable is only used to offload graphical work. `lspci` doesn't do any graphical work. If you want some sensible confirmation for whether it works, you can download a benchmark, e.g. [GPUTest](http://www.geeks3d.com/gputest/), and run it with and without the variable. Finally, I assure you AMD supports GNU/Linux very well; and the driver for your gen. of GPU is even being worked on by Valve.

Comment: i am sorry i am not clear on the subject, i tried your solution and when i run a game,the game had 1 fps which porbaly means my amd card didnt work,i reckon it used the Intel, after that I typed the lspci command to see if the system "saw" my graphics card, the result it returned was: AMD/ATI Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 but my laptop  according to Dell has the r7 m445, i called Dell support for this matter and they suggested to install windows and see if get the same result, and i installed windows, and when i run dxdiag i got the r7 m445.Iam guessing that 16.04 and amd dont seem to getalong

Comment: @Aenarion have you used radeonsi or AMDGPU-pro? If the later is the case, then maybe something went wrong with driver installation, it's something to be debugged, but I'm not sure I can help very much because my GPU is old, i.e. not supported by AMDGPU-pro, so I'd be giving somewhat blind advises. But if the earlier the case, please add to your post an output of `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears` *(you may need to instal `mesa-utils` for `glxgears`. Technically, any graphical app would be fine, but, well, I just can be sure on certain properties of `glxgears`)*.

Comment: @Aenarion regarding the naming convention — it's somewhat longer explanation to put to a comment, so I put it to the end of my answer.